# ¿Cómo hacer una copia de seguridad en Base De Datos SQL Server desde Visual Basic?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, base-de-datos

Tengo una conexión a una base de datos desde Visual Basic a SQL Server, pero no sé cómo puedo hacer para crear una copia de seguridad y restaurarla.

Comment: te recomiendo que hagas un stored procedure y que en sql hagas una copia de tu base de datos..

Comment: ojo con hacer una copia que los IDs se rompen, mejor usa las herramientas de la base de datos que pueden automatizarse para hacer la tarea desatendida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día, aquí te dejo un [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewi2x11jzp0) de Youtube de como realizar un respaldo desde visual basic, ahí encontrarás el código, paso a paso, con lo cual podrás lograr uno de los dos puntos que deseas realizar. Después [aquí](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiP5vj6xpzQAhVQzGMKHeIxBXwQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elguille.info%2FNET%2FADONET%2Fsqlserver_restore_backup_vb.aspx&usg=AFQjCNHNjutMtJ7MgFscp-8DZVRJULZbDA&sig2=z0sN4foSiOtK0SYsrfziOA&bvm=bv.138169073,d.eWE&cad=rja) está el código para restaurar el respaldo de la base de datos.

En el caso del tutorial de youtube, por causas obvias no puedo agregarte el código, pero en el segundo caso sí, así que aquí está:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnRestore_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnRestore.Click
        Me.btnRestore.Enabled = False
        Me.btnRestore.Text = "Restaurando..."
        Me.btnRestore.Refresh()

        Dim sBackup As String = "RESTORE DATABASE " & Me.txtBase.Text & _
                                " FROM DISK = '" & Me.txtBackup.Text & "'" & _
                                " WITH REPLACE"

        Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        csb.DataSource = Me.txtServidor.Text
        ' Es mejor abrir la conexión con la base Master'


        csb.InitialCatalog = "master"
        csb.IntegratedSecurity = True

        Using con As New SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString)
            Try
                con.Open()

                Dim cmdBackUp As New SqlCommand(sBackup, con)
                cmdBackUp.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Se ha restaurado la copia de la base de datos.", _
                                "Restaurar base de datos", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, _
                                "Error al restaurar la base de datos", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try
        End Using

        Me.btnRestore.Text = "Restaurar copia"
        Me.btnRestore.Enabled = True
        Me.btnRestore.Refresh()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Además agrego (aunque no es relacionado con la pregunta) la forma de hacer un [job](http://decabo.com/tecnologia/2011/02/07/sql-server-creacion-de-jobs-para-hacer-copias-de-seguridad/) en SQL Server, para que se hagan respaldos de bases de datos automáticamente (Sin necesidad de que haya alguna intervención de código).

Espero y te sirva la información que te brindo

Answer (score 0):

Yo ejecuto el siguiente procedimiento almacenado:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SISACLatin.BackupEjecutar] (@Ruta Varchar(MAX), @NombreBd Varchar(1000), @Extension Varchar(6))
    AS
    BEGIN
Declare @Fecha varchar(MAX)
Declare @Archivo varchar(MAX)
Declare @NombreBackup varchar(MAX)

Set @Fecha = CONVERT(Varchar(max), GETDATE(),23)+'%'+REPLACE(CONVERT(Varchar(max), GETDATE(),8),':','')
PRINT @Fecha

Set @Archivo = @Ruta+'\'+@NombreBd+@Fecha+@Extension
Set @NombreBackup = 'Backup completo '+@NombreBd

-- WITH NOFORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'D_SQLServerBackups', NAME = ;
BACKUP DATABASE @NombreBd TO DISK = @Archivo WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = @NombreBackup, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;

    END
```